# scope of imported variables

Tags: python, import, global, python-3.8

I've hit a situation in  a python3.8 script where after importing a bunch of variables from an external file,  in some functions they can be accessed ok while in others not.  E.g. a constant `min_time_n_clicks` is defined in the file `tm_constants.py` with a simple declation,

```
min_time_n_clicks=10
```

Pardons that this isn't a reproducible example as the full code is pretty long, its an attempt to show what I've hit: in one function  function `check_scope` I can access variables by using `from tm_constants import *` while another function `check_for_limiting` can't see them - it hits

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min_time_n_clicks' referenced before assignment`

Why would this be? I never remove the variables using del or the like and in the pycharm debugger I use, the offending variable (`min_time_n_clicks`) can be seen and evaluated even when in the scope of the offending function .  Is accessing using the dot notation the preferred method, and if so why ?

```
from tm_constants import *
import tm_constants

def check_scope():

    print(f'ok: {min_time_n_clicks}')
    print(f'ok: {tm_constants.min_time_n_clicks}')

def check_for_limiting():
    print(tm_constants.min_time_n_clicks)
    tm_constants.min_time_n_clicks = 0  # ok 
    print(min_time_n_clicks)
    min_time_n_clicks = 0 # not ok !!!
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem could be, and cannot reproduce the issue without a minimal definition of the module `tm_constants`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get an `UnboundLocalError` without any assignment to the name in the function.

Comment: With `tm_constants.py` and a `tmp.py` defined as shown (plus calls `check_scope()` and `check_for_limiting(None)`), `python3 tmp.py` does not produce an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @chepner yeah i overedited my functions , the orig. had some assignments.  The code is too long for me to add in its entirety and isn;t meant to be a reproducible example

Comment: Still no error. If, however, you try to print the value of the *global* `min_time_n_clicks` before the assignment, you will get an error. It's the *presense* of an assignment that marks the name as local, not the actual assignment at runtime. That is, you can't use a global and a local of the same name in the same scope.

Comment: yes with your help i've gotten to the MRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce an `UnboundLocalError`:

```
def check_for_limiting(browser):
    print(min_time_n_clicks)
    min_time_n_clicks = 0
```

When the function definition is compiled, the parser marks `min_time_n_clicks` as a local variable based on the assignment. That means *all* uses of the name in the function scope refer to the local variable, even those uses that occur *before* the assignment. This is true even if the assignment cannot be reached at runtime:

```
def check_for_limiting(browser):
    print(min_time_n_clicks)  # Still raises an UnboundLocalError
    if False:
        min_time_n_clicks = 0
```

---

If your intention is to assign to the global variable, you need to use `global` to mark the name as global:

```
def check_for_limiting(browser):
    global min_time_n_clicks

    print(min_time_n_clicks)
    min_time_n_clicks = 0
```

There is no issue with the dotted access because there is no variable named `min_time_n_clicks` in that case; there is only the global name `tm_constants` that refers to an object with an *attribute* named `min_time_n_clicks`. Further note that assigning directly to `min_time_n_clicks` will *not* change the value of `tm_constants.min_time_n_clicks`, as they are two different references to the same object. Changing one reference does not change the other.